# Share image link on facebook comment or message

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have an **image** link with only image. I would like to share it through Fb, either messenger or comment. However, the image only shows for awhile before stop loading. In **scraper**, it appears broken image. On other places, an soulless white background. Any suggestion on how to overcome?

What I see:

- When the image shows, FB **scraper** warns that it can't download (Could not retrieve data from URL.)
- When the images dies, FB **scraper** warns about og:tag or can't download.

I would like it to only be image, and not website.

Comment: _“However, the image only shows for awhile before stop loading”_ – when, where, what does that mean?

Comment: In scrapper, it appears broken. On other places, an soulless white background